# OGR UnionCascaded gives strange lines (flat polygons)

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, union, polygonize

I'm using OGR to perform a union using UnionCascaded. All my polygons have been created by GDAL polygonize which ensures that all polygons follow pixel edges and should therefore align nicely. But I get these strange flat polygons looking like lines:

[image: Example of union result with strange flat polygons]

They are positioned at locations where two polygons met before they where unioned.

**Can you recognise this pattern and what lead to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating this a bit further left me thinking it could be numerical errors. Using the *zero-buffer* trick worked, but ofcourse slowed my process down considerably.